# django unable to show search result

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a search function on my home page. What it should does is that when the user clicked the on the Search button, the url should change from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search=xxx` and return the search result.

Currently after pressing the search button the page does not change at all and I dont know what went wrong.

I'm following a tutorial from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Rct7Na0UQ

**views.py**

```
class HomeView(ListView):
model = Item
paginate_by = 10
template_name = "home.html"

def SearchFilter(request, Item):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    myFilter = ItemFilter(request.GET, queryset=items)
    items = myFilter.qs

    context = {
        'Item': items,
        'myfilter': myFilter
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters

from .models import *

class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = {
            'title': ['icontains'],
            'price': ['exact', 'contains'],
            'discount_price': ['exact', 'contains'],
            'category': ['exact', 'contains'],
        }
```

**home.html**

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get">
        <div class="md-form my-0">
          {{myFilter.form}}
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add action url in the form tag

```
<form action="YOUR_SEARCH_URL" method="get">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: I'm following a tutorial from youtube. The tutorial works without adding ``action``. I added the link to the question